# SQL to find Blog Posts That Don't Have Angry Comments

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Say my blog has a table of Posts.  Posts can have Comments, and the Comment table rows have FKs to the Post on which they are commenting.  So finding all Posts that have **no Comments** at all can be done by selecting "comments.id is null".

But let's add a Comment.tone column, which can have one of 5 values like "supporting", or "angry", or whatever.

Now I want to find all Posts that don't have angry comments.  The SQL technique of selecting "comments.id is NULL" doesn't work when you ask for "all the rows that don't exist, but if they did, would have had the value of 'angry' ".

So how do I select them?

Comment: By the way, my actual problem has nothing to do with blogs, posts, or comments.  I used this example because it is simple and familiar.  Please don't advise me how to use some Wordpress trick to solve this artificial problem!

Comment: does name of the models are Post and Comment?

Answer (score 1):

try this out assuming that name of the models are Post and Comment.

and they have relation like

```
Post has_many :comments

Comment belongs_to :post

Post.joins(:comments).where(tone: 'angry').all
```

not have angry

```
Post.joins(:comments).where('tone is not in (?)', ['angry']).all

or 

Post.joins(:comments).where(tone: ['happy', 'abc']).all
```

Comment: That will give me all Posts with angry comments.
But what I want is all Posts that **don't** have any angry comments.

Comment: The revised query will provide all comments on the post that are not angry.  But what I want is all posts that have no angry comments. So I might get tens of thousands of posts that have comments which are not angry, but still miss thousands of other posts that have no comments at all.

Comment: My friend Ho-Sheng Hsiao just sent me an email pointing out what a poor technology SQL is for queuing events.  (the actual problem could be looked at as an event queue, though there is no way to see that from the abstracted Post-with-Comments example I posted here. Once the event gets handled, I can create rows that are like Comments on a Post).  He suggested Redis.

Comment: So far, I have not found any SQL approach that works in an acceptable amount of time when you have millions of "posts".  I assumed a SQL solution to a problem that could be viewed from an entirely different perspective, sidestepping the SQL problem.